# How do I solve the problem of modules not found in angular application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm

I have an angular application that uses two libraries locally, however, when trying to build everything ending up with an error of modules not found, but I thought it was some problems of undeclared dependencies, or imported, but everything is fine.

For better understanding, I have: Two local libraries that are used by a test application, where this application consumes both libs, but in the compilation it presents the error of modules not found:

`Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@ngx-formly/example-kendo' in 'C:\SamuelPierre\Example\Repositório\NgBibliotecas\NgBibliotecas\projects\framework-example\src\app\shared'

Error: projects/framework-example/src/app/app.component.ts:1:34 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@example-library/identity' or its corresponding type declarations.

1 import { UserTokenService } from '@example-library/identity';
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~`

This error appears for all dependencies, but my main file has all the necessary imports and declarations.

Also, "npm install" to install the libraries doesn't help as they are accessed locally. I've already cleaned the node modules, reinstalled npm, everything is ok, but the problem persists.

Comment: can you show us your code so we can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you should run `npm install` or when it just one module just do `npm install <module name> -save`

Comment: They are accessed locally.

Answer (score 1):

Try (in Terminal):

```
npm install
```

Comment: They are accessed locally.